# Activity not found exception when clicking on the image

Tags: android

i am getting following error:
log is:

```
android.content.ActivityNotFoundException:
No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW 
dat=android.resource://com.isummation.customgallery/2130837504 typ=image/* }
```

my code is as:

```
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
Uri hacked_uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://com.isummation.customgallery/" + R.drawable.a);
intent.setDataAndType(hacked_uri, "image/*");
startActivity(intent);
```

manifest.xml is as:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
</intent-filter>
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```

any suggestion?
thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try putting all actions/categories in the same intent filter, as opposed to the two different ones you currently have:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />    
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```

Also make sure you added the intent filter to the correct activity. For an example, check out the [Note Pad example](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/intents/intents-filters.html#npex).

Answer (score 0):

i can't see setName() in ur code . usually Activity not found means we set a name to intent but no Activity tag in menifest with this name exist . so please check